# RenderScript Element packed into a single 24 bit field with 24 bit alignment

Tags: android, renderscript

When processing RGB data in RS through `kernel`-`Allocation` construct, I'm using uchar3/uchar4 data-type in RS to process RGB data. However both of these datatypes are single 32 bit field with 32 bit alignment. This way I lose out on r-component of 2nd pixel.

The RS developer docs suggests `Element.Builder` for creating custom data-types. However its usage doesn't quite give me a single 24-bit-field-with-24-bit-alignment element with most of the primitive datatypes (U8, RGB_888, etc.) . Is there a prescribed way to use/create a 24 bit field 24 bit aligned element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Typically non-power of 2 alignment will create all sorts of havok for hardware units.  Some load units will bus fault, other runs at 1/4 speed.  For this reason the Vec3 types are all stored as if they were vec4.

Comment: Thanks for getting back on this. 
Does writing a RS kernel function always ensure that the code runs on GPU? How can we check whether a particular RS function (kernel or invokable) runs on GPU or CPU? And can we force them to run on GPU?